# last accessed time gets updated though I do not open it

Tags: lastaccesstime

Usually it's the other way around, but I've been checking file properties and it shows the current date and time - even files I never actually opened. A couple of days ago I got a proper reading, but today others are properly displayed, others not, anyone know anything that could help? My OS is XP x32 pro. 
In the case of images, if they are displayed as thumbnails, should that change the time?
Under these circumstances, would a digital forensics program get the proper time or would it also cause it to update?

Comment: *By other way around I mean that people ask about opening a file and the time not being updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of digital forensics manuals saying that Last Accessed can be modified even by right clicking, which I definitely did. 
 Since they do display it, they should be unaffected. As for thumbnails, it should remain a mystery, unless someone has forensics tools, PM me to update the answer if so.